# Jquery if between 2 numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following Jquery to try and add a class when on a certain slide number (using Royalslider). The below code works well on individual slide numbers, but you will notice I am also trying to achieve the same effect on a range of numbers - for example, between slides 5-9. This isn't working however, and only fires for the first number in the array.

Any help appreciated!

**JS**

```
// Track slide number and add class
this.rsInstance().ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function() {
    if( this.currSlideId === 1) {
        $('.what').addClass('current');
    } 
    else {
        $('.what').removeClass('current');
    }
    if( this.currSlideId === 2) {
        $('.why').addClass('current');
    } 
    else {
        $('.why').removeClass('current');
    }
    if( this.currSlideId === ( 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 )) {
        $('.accolades').addClass('current');
    } 
    else {
        $('.accolades').removeClass('current');
    }
});
```

Comment: `5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9` will always return `5`

Comment: Thanks Rayon, appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simple?

```
if (this.currSlideId >= 5 && this.currSlideId <= 9) {
    $('.accolades').addClass('current');
} else {
    $('.accolades').removeClass('current');
}
```

However, If you want to use an array, then use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), it returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```
if ([5,6,7,8,9].indexOf(this.currSlideId) > -1) {
    $('.accolades').addClass('current');
} else {
    $('.accolades').removeClass('current');
}
```

The above function will work in IE9+, for older browser's you can use either [PolyFill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) or [jQuery.inArray(value, array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/))

```
if (jQuery.inArray(this.currSlideId,[5,6,7,8,9]) > -1){
    $('.accolades').addClass('current');
} else {
    $('.accolades').removeClass('current');
}
```

---

You can further improve your code using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) method

```
$('.accolades').toggleClass('current', this.currSlideId >= 5 && this.currSlideId <= 9);
```

*Complete*

```
// Track slide number and add class
this.rsInstance().ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function() {
    $('.what').toggleClass('current', this.currSlideId === 1);
    $('.why').toggleClass('current', this.currSlideId);
    $('.accolades').toggleClass('current', this.currSlideId >= 5 && this.currSlideId <= 9);
});
```

Comment: Thank you SatPal, what a great answer. I will test this as soon as possible and get back to you with results!

Comment: Brilliant @Satpal, tested and all working. Thank you also for improving my code, I knew it could be simpler but didn't know how! Appreciate your help!